# How to list all tables in PhpMyAdmin's left menu?

Tags: php, database-design, phpmyadmin

Does anyone know how to list every table (disable the pagination) in PhpMyAdmin's left menu? I have over 250 tables in my DB and now we are seeing the pageination. It's very annoying having to go back and forth and would be much easier to have them all listed.

We found the following variable:

```
$cfg['LeftDisplayTableFilterMinimum']  = 30
```

However, when I put it into our config file it doesn't appear to have any affect.

In the [Documentation](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#Left_frame_setup) it says to set it to a big number to disable, we tried that as well with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

#### Update:

Thanks to @Cloudkiller, there's another configuration setting that might need to be changed (as of 4.3.6) in addition to Update V4:

[**`$cfg['FirstLevelNavigationItems']`**](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_FirstLevelNavigationItems)

### Update V4:

According to [**Configuration Docs**](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html), you can modify:

[**`$cfg['MaxNavigationItems']`**](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxNavigationItems)

> The number of items that can be displayed on each page of the navigation tree.

#### Can also try:

[**`$cfg['MaxTableList']`**](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxTableList)

> The maximum number of table names to be displayed in the main panel’s list (except on the Export page). This limit is also enforced in the navigation panel when in Light mode.

Comment: In fact, `MaxTableList` should be (as seen in the documentation) for `The maximum number of table names to be displayed in the RIGHT panel's list.`. Note the "RIGHT" panel, not the left one.

Answer (score 74):

Here's how I did this (using v. 4.0.5 w/ "pmahomme" theme on my shared host):

1. Go to the phpMyAdmin Home page (house icon).
2. Under "Appearance Settings", go to "More Settings...".
3. Select "Navigation Panel" in the second row from the top.
4. Change the number in "Maximum items in branch".
5. Click "Save"
6. Bob's your uncle!

[image: phpmyadmin settings screenshot]

Comment: When I log out and login again, it is back to showing 50 entries by default.

Answer (score 42):

According to phpMyAdmin it is MaxNavigationItems:

```
$cfg['MaxNavigationItems']
Type: integer
Default value:  25
```

The number of items that can be displayed on each page of the navigation tree.

Comment: Additional clarification: This is the setting you want if you're trying to remove the table list pagination that occurs in the nav menu in version 4.0 (new release as of this writing).

Comment: yep, that was the original question, wasn't it?

Comment: Not exactly, I don't see anything in the original question specifying when this became an issue. If you like, call it Google fodder.

Answer (score 14):

I found it via a slight variation to mpemburn's answer for my local version (4.0.4) installed via Xampp.

1. Go to the phpMyAdmin Home page (house icon).
2. Click "Settings" tab
3. Select "Navigation Panel"
4. Change the number in "Maximum items in branch".
5. Click "Save"
6. Bob's your uncle!

Comment: In v4.5 after clicking "Navigation Panel" you now need to click the "Navigation tree" sub-panel to see the "Maximim Items in the branch" setting.

Answer (score 6):

As of phpMyAdmin 4.8.5.

1. Click the cog icon at the top left under the phpMyAdmin logo.
2. Click on the `Navigation Tree` tab.
3. Increase the number of `Maximum items in branch`.

[image: Image of how to edit the table limit in PHPMyAdmin]

Answer (score 3):

When I use the settings from the interface, then log out and login again, it is back to default, i.e. showing `50` entries.

Solution for 5.0+:

1. Rename `config.sample.inc.php` to `config.inc.php` (don't forget the "inc" part)
2. Open file.
3. Add to last line: `$cfg['MaxNavigationItems'] = 500;`
4. Open PhpMyAdmin and the navigation items are listend (`500` entries).

Reference: [Configuration file](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html)

Reference: [$cfg['MaxNavigationItems']](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxNavigationItems)

Answer (score 1):

I have just upgraded to **4.3.6** and had to add another setting:

> [$cfg['FirstLevelNavigationItems']](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_FirstLevelNavigationItems)

in addition to:

```
$cfg['MaxTableList'];
$cfg['MaxNavigationItems'];
```

Comment: Just upgraded to 4.3.6 as well and was going crazy trying to find this.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to get ALL the tables listed in the left pane.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation these are the configurations that should do the job:

```
$cfg['NavigationTreeDisplayItemFilterMinimum'] = 500;
$cfg['FirstLevelNavigationItems'] = 500;
```

Comment: can you include a reference to the documentation where it states such?